# Premiere Pro - Animation - rotate question mark about its "dot"

Tags: premiere

I would like to create a simple animation effect in premiere pro where a question mark (text) is rotated about its dot. However, what I can only manage to accomplish is to rotate the question mark about its center.

### Question

What is the least pain-staking method for rotating a question mark about it's dot? Or, equivalently, is there a way to configure the axis of rotation for an object (text or otherwise)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The least pain-staking method? Open After Effects, press "y" to move the anchor point and drag it over the dot. If you rotate now, the rotation is happening from the anchor-point.

Comment: Cool, but there is no native adobe premiere method for this?